# How to set search button center on action bar?

Tags: android

I want set search button center on action bar of tablet. I don't know how to do it?

See this [Image](http://assets.phonedog.com/shared/images/2014/10/183732-androidlollipopdevices.jpg)

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: refer this tutorial: http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/

Comment: I want set search button center action bar

Answer (score 0):

i think `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` works for you.
From [docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) you should add showAsAction attribute to always or ifRoom
i.e:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: I want set search button center action bar

Comment: see on tablet, search button it center action bar http://assets.phonedog.com/shared/images/2014/10/183732-androidlollipopdevices.jpg